# $p$-th power roots of unity: why $p$ prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

Let $p$ be prime, and let $Z=\{z\in \Bbb C: z^{p^n}=1 \text{ for some } n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$.

> I see that $Z$ is indeed group, but, I wonder if we can replace '$p$ is prime' with '$p$ any positive integer'?

I proved $Z$ is indeed a group by showing that it is subgroup of group of roots of unity: $Z$ indeed contains identity, if $x,y$ are in $Z$, then $x^{p^k}=1$ and $y^{p^l}=1$ for some $k,l\in\Bbb Z^+$ $(xy)^{\text{lcm} (p^k,p^l)}=1$ and $x^{-1}$ lies indeed in $Z$. I thought that it was ${\text{lcm} (p^k,p^l)}=1$ where '$p$ is prime' was needed, to see that ${\text{lcm} (p^k,p^l)}$ is indeed positive power of $p$. But I was wrong.

If taking $p$ is positive integer works, then why do we cherish the '$p$ prime' version

Comment: If so, why the $p$ prime version is cherihed?

Comment: If $p$ is prime then the $p$ roots of unity form a field.

Comment: The reason probably comes up later in what $Z$ is used for.  What happens if you try $$z^{6^n} = 1$$ for some $n$ in that later material?  Of course $z^{4^n}=0\quad\text{for some }n$ is the same as $z^{2^n}=0\quad\text{for some }n$

Comment: The [Prüfer p-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) is probably only defined for $p$ prime because of Chinese remainder theorem applied to $\varinjlim_\limits{n} \Bbb Z/r^n \Bbb Z$.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are relative prime, $z_1$ is a primitive $a$th root of unity, and $z_2$ is a primitive $b$th root of unity, then $z_1z_2$ is a primitive $ab$th root of unity: clearly it is an $ab$th root of unity; and if $1 = (z_1z_2)^n = z_1^nz_2^n$, then $z_2^n = (z_1)^{-n}$, and while $z_2^n$ has order dividing $b$, $z_1^{-n}$ has order dividing $a$, hence they both have order $1$; i.e., $z_2^n=z_1^n=1$, so $ab|n$. Thus, the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid z^{k^n}=1\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ decomposes as a product of the sets for primes dividing $k$.

Comment: In particular, the group with $p$ prime is *indecomposable* (it cannot be written as a direct product of nontrivial proper subgroups), whereas the one for arbitrary $k$ is *decomposable*: it is a direct product of proper subgroups.